# change color of input text using python curses

Tags: python, text, terminal, ncurses

I'm developing a text game using python's wrapper library for curses.
I would like text typed in by the user to be a different color from text output by the game. I've had no problems defining color pairs for the output text, but I can't figure out how to change the input text to display different colors as the user is actively typing.

Currently, I get all input using the `getstr()` method.

Is this possible with python / curses?

Thanks,
Ian

Comment: You just have to take input using `getch` and display it how you want. Its not like default `input`/`raw_input` method which takes the input from `stdin` and also outputs it to `stdout`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you can initialize the Python curses wrapper with `echo` turned on, if you are using the curses *wrapper*, if turns echo off initially, e.g.,

```
    # Initialize curses 
    stdscr = curses.initscr()

    # Turn off echoing of keys, and enter cbreak mode, 
    # where no buffering is performed on keyboard input 
    curses.noecho()
    curses.cbreak()
```

If curses is not echoing, your program would have to be doing some echoing.  But since you're using `getstr`, that implies you've turned echo on, since the (ncurses) manual page for `getstr` says

> Characters  input  are  echoed  only  if **`echo`** is currently on.  In that case, backspace is echoed as deletion of the previous character  (typically a left motion).

In this case, you could (depending on how your windows are organized) use [`wattrset`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html#curses.window.attrset):

> Set the “background” set of attributes to attr. This set is initially 0 (no attributes).

The "background" refers to the window attributes, which are merged with attributes associated with text that's added to a window.  Since `getstr` won't have any attributes in the text it adds, setting the window attribute "fixes" your problem.  But keep in mind that you'll want to save the original attributes to restore them when `getstr` is done.

The ncurses [*curs_attr*](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_attr.3x.html) manual page explains this.  The [`getstr`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_getstr.3x.html) function uses `waddch` internally (as do `printw`, `addstr`), but its manual page does not mention that.